# Передать переменные из нескольких классов в один

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Нужно передать переменные из 2-х разных классов 3-му. 3-и сутки уже мучаюсь. Все,что можно нагуглить уже попробовал. Ничего не помогает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать. Передается либо одна только переменная, либо вообще ни одной. Какая передается зависит от метода в котором вызвана проверка. Заранее большое спасибо всем откликнувшимся.

Comment: Код приложите, который не работает

Comment: Каким образом вы рассчитываете вам тут могут помочь по тем сведениям, что вы сообщили? Прочитайте [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и отредактируйте свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятно, что именно не получается. Код бы не помешал.

```
 public class TestMe {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.x = 10;
        System.out.println("Class A: X = " + a.x);
        B b = new B();
        b.y = 20;
        System.out.println("Class B: Y = " + b.y);
        C c = new C();
        c.x = a.x;
        c.y = b.y;
        System.out.println("Class C: X = " + c.x + " Y = " + c.y);
    }

}

class A {

    Integer x;

}

class B {

    Integer y;
}

class C {

    Integer x, y;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за ответы. Проблему решил. Ситуация была следующая. Мне нужно было прочитать текст из JTextArea 2х разных классов и и добавить этот текст в переменную 3-го класса. Проблема решилась путем создания 4-го класса, который сохранял поочередно текст и передавал его нужному классу. При чем экземпляр 4-го класса передавался 3-му. через конструкторы 1-го и 2-го. Так все сделать получилось. Еще раз всем большое спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Не за что. Постарайтесь в будущем, пожалуйста, описывать хотя бы так, как вы написали в комментарии. Хотя бы что-откуда-куда.